# how can i change the whole page background color without knowing its size?

Tags: javascript, css

I've wrote a program that changes the page background on every click or key down.

question 1 - I have to give the body - height and width. it won't work without that. it is as if the body has no height at all. is there a way to get something like body=window?

question 2 - how can i get the actual window/screen size via javascript?

```
<style>
  body {
     background-color: yellow;
     height: 800px;
     width: 1400px;
        }
</style>

<body onclick="myFunction()" onkeydown="myFunction()">

script
    var news=0; // to check if new page load -> to go to full screen

    function myFunction() {   
       // GO TO FULL SCREEN ON PAGE LOAD (OR REFRESH)
       if (news==0) {
          var elem = document.documentElement;
          if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
             elem.requestFullscreen();
          } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
             elem.msRequestFullscreen();
          } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
             elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
          } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
             elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
          }
          news = 1; 
       }

       // give the body a new random color
       var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
       var color = '#';
       for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
          color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
       }
       document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;

    }
 </script>
</body>
```

Comment: `<body>` needs to have content before it has height. It's kind of like filling a balloon with air. The more air, the larger the balloon.

Comment: @user3586104 please accept the answer that helped you! You get SO rep for doing so ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give your body 100% height, which will make it take up all of the space available. Generally you must give some fixed height to the parent element so that you can use percentages, but the `html` element is an exception so you can do the following:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

As for getting the dimensions, there are many different methods which give different measures [depending on what you are looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window). In this case I imagine the most relevant is `window.innerHeight`

Comment: Yes and no on the fixed height. Something has to be defined on a parent for percentages to work. If the parent is a relative unit like `rem` percentages still work. `html` inherits from the window.

Comment: I guess the term I was looking for was "defined height" on the parent more than fixed

Comment: ty. almost... i get a vertical scroll bar

Comment: @user3586104 that's because you did not remove the margin that your browser adds to `<body>` by default, use `body { margin: 0; }`.

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

That would give your body a full height of 100% of what's available.

You can then simply change the background color via:

`document.body.style.backgroundColor = color` and you don't need to know the height or set it. (It's already set).

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed with CSS.

```
 body {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background: yellow;
    overflow:auto;
 }
```

Now, body tag will take full width and height of the screen.